# Увеличить высоту блока исходя из родительского блока + заданное значение

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Есть вот такой вот код:

```
<div class="row row_cont">
        <div class="col-sm-3 sidebar">
            <div class="side_mnu">боковое меню</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 cont">
            <div class="menu_top">
                    меню
            </div>
            <div class="posts">
                посты
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Применяется сетка бустрап, блоку .sidebar применен отрицательный margin-top="-168px", нужно чтобы скрипт брал значение высоты блока .row_cont и возвращал его блоку sidebar приплюсовывая 168.
Нашел скрипт который возвращает высоту всем дивам исходя из высоты родительского дива. Но как либо дописать его, чтобы добавлялось значение именно для блока .sidebar, мне не позволяет отсутствие познаний в яваскрипте((

```
function setEqualHeight(columns)
{
    var tallestcolumn = 0;
    columns.each(
        function()
        {
            currentHeight = $(this).height();
            if(currentHeight > tallestcolumn)
            {
                tallestcolumn = currentHeight;
            }
        }
        );
    columns.height(tallestcolumn);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    setEqualHeight($(".row_cont > div"));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var wrapper = $('.row_cont'),
      sidebar = $('.sidebar', wrapper);

  sidebar.height(wrapper.height() + 168);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row row_cont">
        <div class="col-sm-3 sidebar">
            <div class="side_mnu">боковое меню</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 cont">
            <div class="menu_top">
                    меню
            </div>
            <div class="posts">
                посты
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это именно то что нужно)